# SSRS add new page when it should not

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-grouping, page-break

I am using SSRS 2008.

This does not make any sense but it is happening.

I built a report that show invoices based on invoice number.

The problem is that when I move the table up a single pixel it adds a new page in the end (it should not).

I have removed all controls and left just the table and this is still happening.
Can anyone explain to me why this is happening and how to fix it?

Just try it to move the table up a single pixel.

Here is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Report xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2008/01/reportdefinition" xmlns:rd="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/reporting/reportdesigner">
  <Body>
    <ReportItems>
      <Tablix Name="table1">
        <TablixBody>
          <TablixColumns>
            <TablixColumn>
              <Width>4in</Width>
            </TablixColumn>
          </TablixColumns>
          <TablixRows>
            <TablixRow>
              <Height>0.21in</Height>
              <TablixCells>
                <TablixCell>
                  <CellContents>
                    <Textbox Name="ITEMDESC">
                      <CanGrow>true</CanGrow>
                      <KeepTogether>true</KeepTogether>
                      <Paragraphs>
                        <Paragraph>
                          <TextRuns>
                            <TextRun>
                              <Value>=Fields!ITEMDESC.Value</Value>
                              <Style>
                                <FontFamily>Calibri</FontFamily>
                              </Style>
                            </TextRun>
                          </TextRuns>
                          <Style />
                        </Paragraph>
                      </Paragraphs>
                      <rd:DefaultName>ITEMDESC</rd:DefaultName>
                      <Style>
                        <Border>
                          <Style>None</Style>
                        </Border>
                        <PaddingLeft>2pt</PaddingLeft>
                        <PaddingRight>2pt</PaddingRight>
                        <PaddingTop>2pt</PaddingTop>
                        <PaddingBottom>2pt</PaddingBottom>
                      </Style>
                    </Textbox>
                  </CellContents>
                </TablixCell>
              </TablixCells>
            </TablixRow>
            <TablixRow>
              <Height>0.25in</Height>
              <TablixCells>
                <TablixCell>
                  <CellContents>
                    <Textbox Name="Textbox460">
                      <CanGrow>true</CanGrow>
                      <KeepTogether>true</KeepTogether>
                      <Paragraphs>
                        <Paragraph>
                          <TextRuns>
                            <TextRun>
                              <Value />
                              <Style>
                                <FontFamily>Tahoma</FontFamily>
                              </Style>
                            </TextRun>
                          </TextRuns>
                          <Style />
                        </Paragraph>
                      </Paragraphs>
                      <rd:DefaultName>Textbox460</rd:DefaultName>
                      <Style>
                        <Border>
                          <Style>None</Style>
                        </Border>
                        <PaddingLeft>2pt</PaddingLeft>
                        <PaddingRight>2pt</PaddingRight>
                        <PaddingTop>2pt</PaddingTop>
                        <PaddingBottom>2pt</PaddingBottom>
                      </Style>
                    </Textbox>
                  </CellContents>
                </TablixCell>
              </TablixCells>
            </TablixRow>
            <TablixRow>
              <Height>0.25in</Height>
              <TablixCells>
                <TablixCell>
                  <CellContents>
                    <Textbox Name="Textbox451">
                      <CanGrow>true</CanGrow>
                      <KeepTogether>true</KeepTogether>
                      <Paragraphs>
                        <Paragraph>
                          <TextRuns>
                            <TextRun>
                              <Value />
                              <Style>
                                <FontFamily>Tahoma</FontFamily>
                              </Style>
                            </TextRun>
                          </TextRuns>
                          <Style />
                        </Paragraph>
                      </Paragraphs>
                      <rd:DefaultName>Textbox451</rd:DefaultName>
                      <Style>
                        <Border>
                          <Style>None</Style>
                        </Border>
                        <PaddingLeft>2pt</PaddingLeft>
                        <PaddingRight>2pt</PaddingRight>
                        <PaddingTop>2pt</PaddingTop>
                        <PaddingBottom>2pt</PaddingBottom>
                      </Style>
                    </Textbox>
                  </CellContents>
                </TablixCell>
              </TablixCells>
            </TablixRow>
            <TablixRow>
              <Height>0.25in</Height>
              <TablixCells>
                <TablixCell>
                  <CellContents>
                    <Textbox Name="Textbox446">
                      <CanGrow>true</CanGrow>
                      <KeepTogether>true</KeepTogether>
                      <Paragraphs>
                        <Paragraph>
                          <TextRuns>
                            <TextRun>
                              <Value />
                              <Style>
                                <FontFamily>Tahoma</FontFamily>
                              </Style>
                            </TextRun>
                          </TextRuns>
                          <Style />
                        </Paragraph>
                      </Paragraphs>
                      <rd:DefaultName>Textbox446</rd:DefaultName>
                      <Style>
                        <Border>
                          <Style>None</Style>
                        </Border>
                        <PaddingLeft>2pt</PaddingLeft>
                        <PaddingRight>2pt</PaddingRight>
                        <PaddingTop>2pt</PaddingTop>
                        <PaddingBottom>2pt</PaddingBottom>
                      </Style>
                    </Textbox>
                  </CellContents>
                </TablixCell>
              </TablixCells>
            </TablixRow>
            <TablixRow>
              <Height>0.25in</Height>
              <TablixCells>
                <TablixCell>
                  <CellContents>
                    <Textbox Name="Textbox442">
                      <CanGrow>true</CanGrow>
                      <KeepTogether>true</KeepTogether>
                      <Paragraphs>
                        <Paragraph>
                          <TextRuns>
                            <TextRun>
                              <Value />
                              <Style>
                                <FontFamily>Tahoma</FontFamily>
                              </Style>
                            </TextRun>
                          </TextRuns>
                          <Style />
                        </Paragraph>
                      </Paragraphs>
                      <rd:DefaultName>Textbox442</rd:DefaultName>
                      <Style>
                        <Border>
                          <Style>None</Style>
                        </Border>
                        <PaddingLeft>2pt</PaddingLeft>
                        <PaddingRight>2pt</PaddingRight>
                        <PaddingTop>2pt</PaddingTop>
                        <PaddingBottom>2pt</PaddingBottom>
                      </Style>
                    </Textbox>
                  </CellContents>
                </TablixCell>
              </TablixCells>
            </TablixRow>
            <TablixRow>
              <Height>0.25in</Height>
              <TablixCells>
                <TablixCell>
                  <CellContents>
                    <Textbox Name="Textbox436">
                      <CanGrow>true</CanGrow>
                      <KeepTogether>true</KeepTogether>
                      <Paragraphs>
                        <Paragraph>
                          <TextRuns>
                            <TextRun>
                              <Value />
                              <Style>
                                <FontFamily>Tahoma</FontFamily>
                              </Style>
                            </TextRun>
                          </TextRuns>
                          <Style />
                        </Paragraph>
                      </Paragraphs>
                      <rd:DefaultName>Textbox436</rd:DefaultName>
                      <Style>
                        <Border>
                          <Style>None</Style>
                        </Border>
                        <PaddingLeft>2pt</PaddingLeft>
                        <PaddingRight>2pt</PaddingRight>
                        <PaddingTop>2pt</PaddingTop>
                        <PaddingBottom>2pt</PaddingBottom>
                      </Style>
                    </Textbox>
                  </CellContents>
                </TablixCell>
              </TablixCells>
            </TablixRow>
            <TablixRow>
              <Height>0.25in</Height>
              <TablixCells>
                <TablixCell>
                  <CellContents>
                    <Textbox Name="Textbox99">
                      <CanGrow>true</CanGrow>
                      <KeepTogether>true</KeepTogether>
                      <Paragraphs>
                        <Paragraph>
                          <TextRuns>
                            <TextRun>
                              <Value />
                              <Style>
                                <FontFamily>Tahoma</FontFamily>
                              </Style>
                            </TextRun>
                          </TextRuns>
                          <Style />
                        </Paragraph>
                      </Paragraphs>
                      <rd:DefaultName>Textbox99</rd:DefaultName>
                      <Style>
                        <Border>
                          <Style>None</Style>
                        </Border>
                        <PaddingLeft>2pt</PaddingLeft>
                        <PaddingRight>2pt</PaddingRight>
                        <PaddingTop>2pt</PaddingTop>
                        <PaddingBottom>2pt</PaddingBottom>
                      </Style>
                    </Textbox>
                  </CellContents>
                </TablixCell>
              </TablixCells>
            </TablixRow>
          </TablixRows>
        </TablixBody>
        <TablixColumnHierarchy>
          <TablixMembers>
            <TablixMember />
          </TablixMembers>
        </TablixColumnHierarchy>
        <TablixRowHierarchy>
          <TablixMembers>
            <TablixMember>
              <Group Name="table1_SOPNUMBEa">
                <GroupExpressions>
                  <GroupExpression>=Fields!SOPNUMBEa.Value</GroupExpression>
                </GroupExpressions>
                <PageBreak>
                  <BreakLocation>End</BreakLocation>
                </PageBreak>
              </Group>
              <SortExpressions>
                <SortExpression>
                  <Value>=Fields!SOPNUMBEa.Value</Value>
                </SortExpression>
              </SortExpressions>
              <TablixMembers>
                <TablixMember>
                  <Group Name="table1_Details_Group">
                    <DataElementName>Detail</DataElementName>
                  </Group>
                  <TablixMembers>
                    <TablixMember />
                    <TablixMember>
                      <Visibility>
                        <Hidden>true</Hidden>
                      </Visibility>
                    </TablixMember>
                    <TablixMember>
                      <Visibility>
                        <Hidden>true</Hidden>
                      </Visibility>
                    </TablixMember>
                    <TablixMember>
                      <Visibility>
                        <Hidden>true</Hidden>
                      </Visibility>
                    </TablixMember>
                    <TablixMember>
                      <Visibility>
                        <Hidden>true</Hidden>
                      </Visibility>
                    </TablixMember>
                    <TablixMember>
                      <Visibility>
                        <Hidden>true</Hidden>
                      </Visibility>
                    </TablixMember>
                    <TablixMember>
                      <Visibility>
                        <Hidden>true</Hidden>
                      </Visibility>
                    </TablixMember>
                  </TablixMembers>
                  <DataElementName>Detail_Collection</DataElementName>
                  <DataElementOutput>Output</DataElementOutput>
                  <KeepTogether>true</KeepTogether>
                </TablixMember>
              </TablixMembers>
            </TablixMember>
          </TablixMembers>
        </TablixRowHierarchy>
        <DataSetName>DataSet1</DataSetName>
        <Top>0.32987cm</Top>
        <Left>0.03528cm</Left>
        <Height>1.71in</Height>
        <Width>4in</Width>
        <Style />
      </Tablix>
    </ReportItems>
    <Height>1.83987in</Height>
    <Style />
  </Body>
  <Width>7.42546in</Width>
  <Page>
    <PageHeight>11.69in</PageHeight>
    <PageWidth>8.27in</PageWidth>
    <LeftMargin>0.25in</LeftMargin>
    <RightMargin>0.25in</RightMargin>
    <TopMargin>0.25in</TopMargin>
    <BottomMargin>0.25in</BottomMargin>
    <Style />
  </Page>
  <AutoRefresh>0</AutoRefresh>
  <DataSources>
    <DataSource Name="GPDB_CITYW">
      <DataSourceReference>GPDB_CITYW</DataSourceReference>
      <rd:SecurityType>None</rd:SecurityType>
      <rd:DataSourceID>71845ba6-a656-4115-a595-12b9a4b3017f</rd:DataSourceID>
    </DataSource>
  </DataSources>
  <DataSets>
    <DataSet Name="DataSet1">
      <Query>
        <DataSourceName>GPDB_CITYW</DataSourceName>
        <QueryParameters>
          <QueryParameter Name="@SOPNo">
            <Value>=Parameters!SOPNo.Value</Value>
          </QueryParameter>
          <QueryParameter Name="@BatchNo">
            <Value>=Parameters!BatchNo.Value</Value>
          </QueryParameter>
        </QueryParameters>
        <CommandText>EXEC AllInvoice @SOPNo, @BatchNo</CommandText>
        <rd:UseGenericDesigner>true</rd:UseGenericDesigner>
      </Query>
      <Fields>
        <Field Name="ITEMDESC">
          <DataField>ITEMDESC</DataField>
          <rd:TypeName>System.String</rd:TypeName>
        </Field>
        <Field Name="SOPNUMBEa">
          <DataField>SOPNUMBEa</DataField>
          <rd:TypeName>System.String</rd:TypeName>
        </Field>
      </Fields>
    </DataSet>
  </DataSets>
  <ReportParameters>
    <ReportParameter Name="SOPNo">
      <DataType>String</DataType>
      <AllowBlank>true</AllowBlank>
      <Prompt>SOPNo</Prompt>
    </ReportParameter>
    <ReportParameter Name="BatchNo">
      <DataType>String</DataType>
      <AllowBlank>true</AllowBlank>
      <Prompt>Batch No</Prompt>
    </ReportParameter>
  </ReportParameters>
  <Language>en-US</Language>
  <ConsumeContainerWhitespace>true</ConsumeContainerWhitespace>
  <rd:ReportUnitType>Inch</rd:ReportUnitType>
  <rd:ReportID>3cdad144-fdac-4806-9f36-2841d5131ecd</rd:ReportID>
</Report>
```

Comment: Just guessing.. but have you set report properties to consumecontainerwhitespace = true?

Comment: @Harry it is true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has to do with the "Group Properties" | "Page Breaks" for the row group named `table1_SOPNUMBEa`. You'll need to untick the <kbd>Also at the end of a group</kbd> checkbox.

---

#### Screenshot of "Group Properties" | "Page Breaks"

[image: screenshot]

---

#### Here are the example records I used:

```
SELECT tbl.* FROM (VALUES
  ( 'A', 1)
, ( 'B', 2)
, ( 'C', 3)
, ( 'D', 4)
, ( 'E', 5)
) tbl ([ITEMDESC], [SOPNUMBEa])
```

---

*side-note: It's always nice to find another SSRS Developer in Melbourne.* :)

Comment: No worries, glad I could help.